# How much of memory is allocated for php://output?

Tags: php, memory, stream, wrapper

I am doing something like

```
$fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
fwrite( $fh, $contents );
fclose($fh);
```

How much of memory will be available to write data?

Comment: If your running this on a web server you will be restricted to the maximum size set in your php.ini file If your running it in cli your sting can be up to 2 gig http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.string.php .

Comment: @JasonK I am running this on server. which parameter's maximum size? Can you please let me know?

Comment: memory_limit is what you need to look for. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php